# What are the relations between overfitting and susceptibility to adversarial perturbations in classification?

Tags: regularization, overfitting, adversarial-example

For simplicity I am asking this question for a binary classification problem. In the non-robust case, for a dataset $(x_i, f(x_i))$, $i=1,\dots N$ with $x_i$ drawn iid from a distribution $D$, we would like to minimize the error probability $\mathbb{P}_{X\sim D}[h(X)\neq f(X)]$ for some hypothesis $h$ from a hypothesis set. In the robust case, we would like to minimize $\mathbb{P}_{X\sim D}[\exists z \text{ such that } |z|<\epsilon \text{ and } h(X+z)\neq f(X+z)]$ for a robustness parameter $\epsilon$. This seems related to the problem of reducing overfitting by introducing regularization, since when we regularize well small changes in the input result in small changes in the output (for example in a linear classifier).

Are there any concrete relations between these two problems?